# Convert data frame to list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apply

I am trying to go from a data frame to a list structure in R (and I know technically a data frame is a list). I have a data frame containing reference chemicals and their mechanisms different targets. For example, estrogen is an estrogen receptor agonist. What I would like is to transform the data frame to a list, because I am tired of typing out something like:

```
refchem$chemical_id[refchem$target=="AR" & refchem$mechanism=="Agonist"]
```

every time I need to access the list of specific reference chemicals. I would much rather access the chemicals by:

```
refchem$AR$Agonist
```

I am looking for a general answer, even though I have given a simplified example, because not all targets have all mechanisms.

This is really easy to accomplish with a loop:

```
example <- data.frame(target=rep(c("t1","t2","t3"),each=20),
                      mechan=rep(c("m1","m2"),each=10,3),
                      chems=paste0("chem",1:60))
oneoption <- list()
for(target in unique(example$target)){
  oneoption[[target]] <- list()
  for(mech in unique(example$mechan)){
    oneoption[[target]][[mech]] <- as.character(example$chems[ example$target==target & example$mechan==mech ])
  }
}
```

I am just wondering if there is a more clever way to do it. I tried playing around with `lapply` and did not make any progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `split`:

```
split(refchem, list(refchem$target, refchem$mechanism))
```

Should do the trick.

The new way to access would be `refchem$AR.Agonist`

Comment: Thanks! This is mostly what I was looking for. Is there a way to drop the factors that do not have any entries without manually listing them in the `drop` argument?

Comment: Since `drop` is logical, you can just set `drop=TRUE` and `R` should do it for you.

Answer (score 4):

If you make a keyed data.table instead, ...

- you'll still have all the data in one data.frame (instead of a possibly-nested list of many);
- you may find iterating over these subsets nicer; and
- the syntax is pretty clean:

To access a subset:

```
DT[.('AR','Agonist')]
```

To do something for each group, that will be `rbind`ed together in the result:

```
DT[,{do stuff},by=key(DT)]
```

Similar to `aggregate()`, any list of vectors of the correct length can go into the `by`, not just the key.

Finally, `DT` came from...

```
 require(data.table)
 DT <- data.table(refchem,key=c('target','mechanism'))
```

Comment: I have been putting off learning the data.table package. It's probably time.

Comment: @dayne I did that for a long time too - but learning it was the best decision I ever made with R. I had once function that was 150 lines of codes and took 5 minutes to run that now runs in 15 seconds and takes up 25 lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a `plyr` function:

```
library(plyr)
dlply(example, .(target, mechan))
```

It has the added advantage of using a function to process the data, if needed (there's an implicit `identity` in the above).